# Unable to see DDL of a View. SQL Oracle Developer Version - 22.2.1.234

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Unable to see DDL of a View when I double click and go to the SQL tab.

I see the "Generating DDL pop up opens and runs, however, no results are shown on the screen.
I have colleagues on much lower version of Oracle and its working fine for them.

SQL Developer Version - 22.2.1.234.
Please help.

Thanks

I double click on the view dand go to the SQL tab.

I see the "Generating DDL pop up opens and runs, however, no results are shown on the screen.
I have colleagues on much lower version of Oracle and its working fine for them.

Comment: This VIEW, is it a VIEW in your schema, or someone else's? If you just want the SQL under the view, you'll also find that on the DETAILS panel

Comment: thank you. this is helpful. yes, this is a view in my schema. I can see the underlying code in the Details panel but don't see this in the SQL panel.

Comment: There is a newer version available (23.1) but i'm not aware of any bugs matching the description of your issue.  Workaround: try running 'ddl view_name' and execute that as a script in the SQL worksheet

Comment: What is result of this statement: `select user, o.owner, o.object_type from all_objects o where object_name = 'THAT_VIEW_NAME';`